# Can't delete a file from a read-only directory in Java using Apache Commons

Tags: java, file, directory, apache-commons

How do I delete a file from a directory without deleting the directory itself in Java? I tried using the `cleanDirectory` method of the `FileUtils` class of the Apache Commons. But it won't delete the file because the folder is set to ReadOnly. How do I get past this constraint? Any ideas?

Comment: Change the permissions on the folder?

Comment: Yes, exactly. How do I do that using Java?

Comment: Did you look at File.setWriteable() and use it on the directory?

Comment: I'll try that and let you know how it goes. Thanks! :)

Comment: If you solved your problem, consider adding your solution as an answer so future readers can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't u use the java.nio.file.Files class? Simply write the following line

```
Files.delete(file.toPath());
```